# Is it possible to alter or delete properties of the global object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, global

I was just reading up stuff about the global object, and was wondering if it would be possible to alter the values of the properties of the global object. I do not know what purpose this would serve, yet am interested.

Take this code for example:

```
Infinity = 4;           //Alter the property Infinity of the global object
                        //This doesn't prompt an error...
console.log(Infinity);  //Yet, for some reason it still prints Infinity, instead of 4.
```

Could you also do this:

```
delete Infinity;
console.log(Infinity)
```

It appears that this is impossible since Infinity still prints Infinity, instead of prompting an undefined error.

Comment: You cannot delete or change to Infinity, its a constant variable.

Comment: Why not, if you are doing it in the global scope?

Comment: Because they are built-in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends - is the property writable/configurable or not?

`Infinity` is neither, as exposed by the following console log:

```
> Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window,'Infinity')
< Object {value: Infinity, writable: false, enumerable: false, configurable: false}
```

However, other global properties, such as `frames`, are configurable:

```
> Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window,'frames')
< Object {value: Window, writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true}
```

So, basically, it depends on how the property is set up.

Comment: In which case, I am surprised no error was prompted.

Comment: It does in strict mode, that's one of the differences between them.

Answer (score 0):

Good question, but the answer is no.  Global objects cannot be modified or deleted.  Global objects are required and built-in to JavaScript.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects